# How to implement tree shaking in angular 7 application

Tags: angular

I want to improve my angular application performance by applying tree shaking concept , can you suggest any references how to implement.

For now am trying to implement tree shaking  by using below reference link

```
https://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/
```

above reference includes some modifications in `webpack.config.js`
but am not seeing that file in application

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

installed webpack using above but still am not able to find `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: angular-cli's `ng build --prod`, that will execute tree shaking for you. Follow the https://angular.io tutorials, they revolve around (make use of) the angular-cli.

Comment: what version of angular are you using ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta Angular 7

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to do anything since you are using angular 7, that is done by default in that version along with default `aot`. all you need to do is just run your build in prod

`ng build --prod`

There some other things you can do to enhance your app performance such as:

1- Use lazy loaded routes.
2- use gzip compressing (done at the server level)
3- Caching
4- Service worker
5- Use Server Side Rendering
6- Minimize Change Detections by using `OnPush` change detection
7- Use `trackBy` in your `ngFor`

Comment: I might be a front end newbie, but how do you use Server Side Rendering with Angular?

Answer (score 2):

There is substitution for tree shaking when you use angular-cli, you just need to set

```
"buildOptimizer": true
```

for project and it will drop unused parts. Also option

```
"optimization": true
```

performs minification that dramatically decreases bundle size. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng build --prod` to enable tree-shaking.

However, the way you inject Angular services may affect tree-shaking. Read more about [Angular service and tree shaking](https://jun711.github.io/web/angular-service-and-how-to-inject-a-service-in-angular/#class-constructor).

Read more about Angular CLI build options [Angular CLI documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build#options).

[image]